# Some codes added to URL when accessing Wikipedia from Gmail and how to prevent it

Tags: gmail, wikipedia, url

What are these numbers and codes that are added to each my Wikipedia link when I click it in Gmail:

[image]

Who is responsible (who is tracking me -- Gmail or Wiki)? How to prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`source`/`ust`/`usg` are Gmail's tracking parameters which are applied to every outgoing link. If you inspect the email, you'll see the `<a>` tag has a `data-saferedirecturl` property containing this link. There are various tools to remove it, e.g. the [URL tracking stripper](https://github.com/newhouse/url-tracking-stripper) Chrome extension.